# MySQL FLOOR function unexpected results

Tags: mysql, floor

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (col_a double(10,2), col_b double(10,2), col_c double(10,2));
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(36.3, 0, 6.3);
```

[image]

**QUERY**

```
SELECT FLOOR(36.3- 0 -6.3), FLOOR(col_a - col_b - col_c) AS calc, col_a, col_b, col_c 
FROM table_name LIMIT 1;
```

**RESULT**

[image]

---

first selected value => `FLOOR(36.3- 0 -6.3)` result in `30`.

second selected value => `FLOOR(col_a - col_b - col_c)` which is equals to `FLOOR(36.3- 0 -6.3)` result in `29` but i am expecting `30`

Why these selects getting two different values?

Comment: Most probably due to floating point storage, result is 29.9999.. and floor result in 29, but I am looking for a reliable source.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html

Answer (score 4):

This is a known problem in MySQL when using the `double` or `float` type, which are not stored internally exactly as we see them.

If you read the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html), you will find a suggested workaround which is to use `decimal` instead of `double`.  You can see in the following Fiddle that all is working as expected when using `decimal(10,2)` as your column types:

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 2):

The values you put in the select are automatically taken as decimal and that's why the result is correct.

```
select 36.3 - 0 - 6.3

--Produces
30.0
```

Floating point types are not stored exactly, so you'll not get the exact results. Try this:

```
select 36.3E0 - 0E0 - 6.3E0

--Produces
29.999999999999996
```

and hence floor gives you 29 in the output.

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html

> Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact
>   values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to
>   problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation
>   dependencies.

And from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-float.html

> A floating-point value as written in an SQL statement may not be the
>   same as the value represented internally.

As Tim advised, you should use Decimal type instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is because floor(-6.3) is 7 .Hence it will become 29.

Further details you can check on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx

Comment: nopes !! This is cause of data type  .for more detail go through the Tim Biegeleisen  answer

Answer (score 0):

Binary floating point it is based on the IEEE 754 standard for float and double.

when you insert value 36.3 into the column which has datatype double then its stores as '`36.29999923706055`' and for 6.3 - > '`6.300000190734863`'

You can convert from here [Link 1](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) or [Link 2](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/)

Now Result `col_a - col_b - col_c` is '29.99999904632569'.
Now you applied floor on it which give you result '29'

FLOOR() returns the largest integer value not greater than a number specified as an argument.

`floor (col_a - col_b - col_c)`

Returns output floor(29.99999904632569) which give you answer - > 29

As Tim advised, you should use Decimal type instead or use below query.

```
        SELECT FLOOR(36.3- 0 -6.3),(col_a - col_b - col_c) 
        AS calc, col_a, col_b, col_c 
        FROM table_name LIMIT 1;
```

Output : 30