# FLOOR() is giving different outputs

Tags: mysql

Executing this code with a value of latehours1 from the database being 0.58, I get an output of 57.

```
SELECT i.id, i.date, i.input1, i.out1, i.input2, i.out2, i.totalhours,  
(FLOOR(latehours1)*60)+FLOOR(((latehours1)-FLOOR(latehours1))*100) AS latehours1,  
(FLOOR(latehours2)*60)+FLOOR(((latehours2)-FLOOR(latehours2))*100) AS latehours2,  
i.isut, i.`daycs`, i.ishalf, i.`break`FROM temp i WHERE id=123;
```

Setting a value for latehours1 gives me an output of 58.

```
SET @latehours1=0.58;
SELECT (FLOOR(@latehours1)*60)+FLOOR(((@latehours1) - FLOOR(@latehours1))*100) AS latehours
```

Comment: Is `latehourrs1` a typo in the query? You are using `latehours1` everywhere else. The difference is just one `r`, but for variables it would mean a completely different variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436844/mysql-floor-function-unexpected-results

Comment: It was a typo in my question, thanks for letting me know.
I see how to solve it thanks to the link from @DanielE. Floating point types are not stored exactly in MySQL.